# Fusion in Sun's core

Tags: nuclear-physics, temperature, astrophysics, fusion

I was reading nuclear physics in which it was mentioned that the coulomb barrier for proton is 400keV corresponding to a temperature of 3 billion Kelvin.I want to know then how does nuclear fusion reactions takes place inside sun's core where average temperature is 0.015 billion kelvin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the sun provide enough energy to fuse protons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/510091/)

Comment: Also, clicking on the first results of a google search for "sun fusion" would yield the answer pretty quickly. @utkarsh basically, you can't apply classical physics logic to protons. Quantum tunneling is a nice little helper in this case.